# No Persistence Exception when persist() is called with an entity that violates a unique constraint

Tags: spring, eclipselink, hsqldb, entitymanager

I have a unique constraint on one property of my entity:

```
Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueByEmail", columnNames = "email"))
public class Player implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    ...
}
```

In my DAO i want to throw an appropriate exception when something tries to create a new player that would violate this constraint:

```
public Player create(String email, String password) {
    Player player = new Player(email, password);
    try {
        em.persist(player);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("I GOT AN EXCEPTION : " + e.getClass());
    }
    return player;
}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens. when i call flush() on the entity manager i get the persistence exception as a result of this call, but not when i call persist().

This behaviour differs from the behaviour of hibernate, so i think i misconfigured something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Persistence.xml:
    
        org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
        model.GameInstanceAccount
        Player

spring applicationContext.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence-unit" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.HSQLPlatform" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i call flush() on the entity manager i get the persistence
>   exception as a result of this call, but not when i call persist()

This is expected behaviour. The persist call only attaches the transient entity to the current persistence session making it managed. The constraint applies in the database and so will only be applied when the persistence session is flushed and new entities are inserted to the database.

This is summed up in this [blog](http://spitballer.blogspot.com/2010/04/jpa-persisting-vs-merging-entites.html) as follows:

> A newly created instance of the entity class is passed to the persist
>   method. After this method returns, the entity is managed and planned
>   for insertion into the database. It may happen at or before the
>   transaction commits or when the flush method is called.

Comment: that may be but hibernate for example triggers insert queries when persist is called and throws persistent exceptions when something is wrong. i want and need this behaviour. is it possible to get it from eclipselink?

Comment: "hibernate for example triggers insert queries when persist is called" - this is not necessarily true. It depends on the strategy used to generate identifiers.